# jQuery and PHP in FOR loop for print_r

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < triggerCount; i++) {

<?php $me = i; ?>

console.log(<?php echo $me; ?>);

jQuery('[data-key="field_5ee8665e2cd7f"] .acf-input .acf-actions [data-event="add-row"]').trigger('click');

jQuery('#ItineraryTab .acf-row input').eq(i).val("<?php print_r($array[$me]); ?>");
}
```

Which loops through a triggerCount variable and sets the input to each value in the array. However, if I use print_r($array[0]); then it shows uses this value from the array and places it into every iteration. How can I loop through this $array so similar to the count it places each value in order into each input in order?

Comment: You are mixing PHP and javascript. Where is the php `$me` defined? how about `$iid`?

Comment: Have updated my question - but I am trying to get the $me in the printer array - so shouldn't it return 0 or 1 or 2 etc?

Comment: Just do `var array = <?= json_encode($array) ?>;` once and don't mix PHP with JS after it.

Comment: You can not assign value of `i` (js) directly to `$me` (php). PHP executes on server side. Browser will execute javascript after he received all the content from the server meaning meaning php execution has finished already.

Comment: Can you explain where/how to use this code?

Comment: Thanks @CarlosCarucce - so how would I need to rewrite this so it can also loop through a counter (for the print_r)

Comment: @Paul VI, place the line I posted above to the head of your code and work with JS array in the loop.

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JS. PHP is evaluated on the server side and JS is evaluated in the web browser. Maybe that's what you want...just understand you can't loop through PHP or use PHP functions (such as `print_r()`) once the page is sent to the browser.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594317/php-embedded-in-javascript/594350#594350

Answer (score -1):

I think you should to use array_push() as:

```
for(var i = 0; i < triggerCount; i++) {

<?php
    $me = i;
    $array = []; 
    array_push($a, $me);
?>

console.log(<?php echo $me; ?>);

jQuery('[data-key="field_5ee8665e2cd7f"] .acf-input .acf-actions [data-event="add-row"]').trigger('click');

jQuery('#ItineraryTab .acf-row input').eq(i).val("<?php print_r($array[$me]); ?>");
}
```